# Select statement takes ages to process

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use this select statement to colect info from different tables, but maintaining the same structure between them and the grouping the results in the end, but since the "fi" table has thousands of rows, it takes ages to process the results. Is there any way to optimise the query below to achieve faster results?

```
select Referencia,Designacao,cor,Tamanho,sum(qtd),entreguesede,stock
from
(
Select  
isnull(ST.REF,'') as Referencia
, fi.design as Designacao
, fi.cor Cor
, fi.tam Tamanho
, sum(case when ft.tipodoc=3 then -fi.qtt else fi.qtt end) as Qtd
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm=1 then sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) EntregueSede
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm<50 then sl.qtt when sl.cm>50 then -sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) Stock

from    fi (nolock) 
inner join ft (nolock) on ft.ftstamp=fi.ftstamp  
inner join td (nolock) on ft.ndoc=td.ndoc and td.regrd=0 
left    join st (nolock) on fi.ref = st.ref or fi.oref = st.ref
left    join sz (nolock) on sz.no = fi.armazem

where fi.composto=0 
and ft.fdata between '20160301' and '20160331'
and ft.anulado=0 
and ft.fno>=0  
and fi.qtt<>0
and ft.tipodoc in(1, 2, 3)
and ((FI.ARMAZEM  between 1000 and 1999) or fi.armazem in(10,20))
and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '%' +  + '%'

group   by FI.REF, fi.design,fi.cor,fi.tam,st.ref

union all

Select  
isnull(ST.REF,'') Referencia
, fi.design Designacao
, fi.cor Cor
, fi.tam Tamanho
,sum(case when ft.tipodoc=3 then -fi.qtt else fi.qtt end) as Qtd
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm=1 then sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) EntregueSede
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm<50 then sl.qtt when sl.cm>50 then -sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) Stock

from    fi (nolock) 
inner join ft (nolock) on ft.ftstamp=fi.ftstamp  
inner join td (nolock) on ft.ndoc=td.ndoc and td.regrd=0 
left    join st (nolock) on fi.ref = st.ref or fi.oref = st.ref
left    join sz (nolock) on sz.no = fi.armazem
where fi.composto=0 
and ft.fdata >= '20150505'
and ft.fdata between '20160301' and '20160331'
and ft.anulado=0 
and ft.fno>=0  
and fi.qtt<>0
and ft.ndoc in (401,501)
and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '%' +  + '%'

group   by FI.REF, fi.design, fi.cor, fi.tam, st.ref

union all

select 
isnull(ST.REF,'') Referencia
, bi.design as Designacao
, bi.cor Cor
, bi.tam Tamanho
,sum(bi.qtt) as Qtd
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm=1 then sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=bi.ref and sl.cor=bi.cor and sl.tam=bi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) EntregueSede
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm<50 then sl.qtt when sl.cm>50 then -sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=bi.ref and sl.cor=bi.cor and sl.tam=bi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) Stock

from bi(nolock)
inner join bo(nolock) on bo.bostamp = bi.bostamp  
inner join bo2(nolock) on bo2stamp = bo.bostamp
inner join ts(nolock) on ts.ndos = bo.ndos and ts.ndos = 60
left join st(nolock) on bi.ref = st.ref
left join sz(nolock) on sz.no = bi.armazem
where bi.composto=0 
and bo.dataobra between '20160301' and '20160331'
and bo2.anulado= 0 
and bo.obrano >= 0
and bi.qtt<>0
and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '%' +  + '%'

group   by bi.REF, bi.design, bi.cor, bi.tam, st.ref
) a
group by Referencia,Designacao,cor,Tamanho,entreguesede,stock
order   by  1,2,3,4,6,7
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the execution plan XML? If so, post it. If not, read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190646.aspx

Comment: Thousands of rows shouldn't cause a problem, have you made sure you have the appropriate indexes?  If you're using SQL server take a look at query analyzer.

Comment: You are aware that `ft.fdata between '20160301' and '20160331'` is not all of the month?

Answer (score 0):

1) 
Is ft.fdata of datatype varchar? If it is a number, use

```
and ft.fdata between 20160301 and 20160331
```

instead of

```
and ft.fdata between '20160301' and '20160331'
```

2)
What is the use of this? That does not make sense to me.

```
and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '%' +  + '%'
```

3) Not relevant for performance, but I would recommend you to not use ORDER BY ColumnNumber

```
order by  1,2,3,4,6,7
```

4) Sub-selects (example of your code below) in columns are usually a really bad idea regarding performance. Try to use it as sub-query if possible.

```
isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm=1 then sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=bi.ref and sl.cor=bi.cor and sl.tam=bi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) EntregueSede
```

5)  Check you indices (as recommended by others already)

6) Sometimes queries combined with "union all" or "union" tend to mess up executions plans (from my experience). Often it helps if you load each query into a temp table first and then combine the temp table. Takes not much time to try it so maybe it helps you.

EDIT:

Here an example for point 4:

```
Select  
isnull(ST.REF,'') as Referencia
, fi.design as Designacao
, fi.cor Cor
, fi.tam Tamanho
, sum(case when ft.tipodoc=3 then -fi.qtt else fi.qtt end) as Qtd
, isnull(EntregueSedeData.EntregueSedeSum ,0) EntregueSede -- <----- USE HERE THE SUM
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm<50 then sl.qtt when sl.cm>50 then -sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) Stock
from    fi (nolock) 
inner join -- <----- JOIN YOUR DATA WITH CALCULATED SUM
(
    select fi.ref,
    fi.cor,
    fi.tam, 
    sum(
            case 
                when sl.cm = 1 then sl.qtt 
                else 0 
            end
        )  
    as EntregueSedeSum
    from sl (nolock) 
    where sl.datalc <= '20160331'
) EntregueSedeData
on sl.ref=fi.ref 
and sl.cor=fi.cor 
and sl.tam=fi.tam 
inner join ft (nolock) on ft.ftstamp=fi.ftstamp  
inner join td (nolock) on ft.ndoc=td.ndoc and td.regrd=0 
left    join st (nolock) on fi.ref = st.ref or fi.oref = st.ref
left    join sz (nolock) on sz.no = fi.armazem
where fi.composto=0 
and ft.fdata between '20160301' and '20160331'
and ft.anulado=0 
and ft.fno>=0  
and fi.qtt<>0
and ft.tipodoc in(1, 2, 3)
and ((FI.ARMAZEM  between 1000 and 1999) or fi.armazem in(10,20))
and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '%' +  + '%'
group   by FI.REF, fi.design,fi.cor,fi.tam,st.ref
```

Here an example for point 6:

```
create table #P1 -- replace xxx by your data type and add NOT NULL where possible
(
    Referencia xxx PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, -- don't know your data model, if Referencia is unique, use it the primary key
    Designacao xxx
    Cor xxx,
    Tamanho xxx,
    EntregueSede xxx,
    Stock xxx
)

insert into #P1
(
    Referencia,
    Designacao,
    Cor,
    Tamanho,
    EntregueSede,
    Stock
)
Select  
isnull(ST.REF,'') as Referencia
, fi.design as Designacao
, fi.cor Cor
, fi.tam Tamanho
, sum(case when ft.tipodoc=3 then -fi.qtt else fi.qtt end) as Qtd
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm=1 then sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) EntregueSede
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm<50 then sl.qtt when sl.cm>50 then -sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) Stock
from    fi (nolock) 
inner join ft (nolock) on ft.ftstamp=fi.ftstamp  
inner join td (nolock) on ft.ndoc=td.ndoc and td.regrd=0 
left    join st (nolock) on fi.ref = st.ref or fi.oref = st.ref
left    join sz (nolock) on sz.no = fi.armazem
where fi.composto=0 
and ft.fdata between '20160301' and '20160331'
and ft.anulado=0 
and ft.fno>=0  
and fi.qtt<>0
and ft.tipodoc in(1, 2, 3)
and ((FI.ARMAZEM  between 1000 and 1999) or fi.armazem in(10,20))
and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '%' +  + '%'
group   by FI.REF, fi.design,fi.cor,fi.tam,st.ref

create table #P2 -- replace xxx by your data type and add NOT NULL where possible
(
    Referencia xxx PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, -- don't know your data model, if Referencia is unique, use it the primary key
    Designacao xxx
    Cor xxx,
    Tamanho xxx,
    EntregueSede xxx,
    Stock xxx
)

insert into #P2
(
    Referencia,
    Designacao,
    Cor,
    Tamanho,
    EntregueSede,
    Stock
)
Select  
isnull(ST.REF,'') Referencia
, fi.design Designacao
, fi.cor Cor
, fi.tam Tamanho
,sum(case when ft.tipodoc=3 then -fi.qtt else fi.qtt end) as Qtd
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm=1 then sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) EntregueSede
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm<50 then sl.qtt when sl.cm>50 then -sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=fi.ref and sl.cor=fi.cor and sl.tam=fi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) Stock
from    fi (nolock) 
inner join ft (nolock) on ft.ftstamp=fi.ftstamp  
inner join td (nolock) on ft.ndoc=td.ndoc and td.regrd=0 
left    join st (nolock) on fi.ref = st.ref or fi.oref = st.ref
left    join sz (nolock) on sz.no = fi.armazem
where fi.composto=0 
and ft.fdata >= '20150505'
and ft.fdata between '20160301' and '20160331'
and ft.anulado=0 
and ft.fno>=0  
and fi.qtt<>0
and ft.ndoc in (401,501)
and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '%' +  + '%'
group   by FI.REF, fi.design, fi.cor, fi.tam, st.ref

create table #P3 -- replace xxx by your data type and add NOT NULL where possible
(
    Referencia xxx PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, -- don't know your data model, if Referencia is unique, use it the primary key
    Designacao xxx
    Cor xxx,
    Tamanho xxx,
    EntregueSede xxx,
    Stock xxx
)

insert into #P3
(
    Referencia,
    Designacao,
    Cor,
    Tamanho,
    EntregueSede,
    Stock
)
select 
isnull(ST.REF,'') Referencia
, bi.design as Designacao
, bi.cor Cor
, bi.tam Tamanho
,sum(bi.qtt) as Qtd
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm=1 then sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=bi.ref and sl.cor=bi.cor and sl.tam=bi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) EntregueSede
, isnull((select sum(case when sl.cm<50 then sl.qtt when sl.cm>50 then -sl.qtt else 0 end) from sl (nolock) where sl.ref=bi.ref and sl.cor=bi.cor and sl.tam=bi.tam and sl.datalc<='20160331'),0) Stock

from bi(nolock)
inner join bo(nolock) on bo.bostamp = bi.bostamp  
inner join bo2(nolock) on bo2stamp = bo.bostamp
inner join ts(nolock) on ts.ndos = bo.ndos and ts.ndos = 60
left join st(nolock) on bi.ref = st.ref
left join sz(nolock) on sz.no = bi.armazem
where bi.composto=0 
and bo.dataobra between '20160301' and '20160331'
and bo2.anulado= 0 
and bo.obrano >= 0
and bi.qtt<>0
and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '%' +  + '%'
group   by bi.REF, bi.design, bi.cor, bi.tam, st.ref

select Referencia,
Designacao,
cor,
Tamanho,
sum(qtd),
entreguesede,
stock
from
(
    select 
    Referencia,
    Designacao,
    Cor,
    Tamanho,
    EntregueSede,
    Stock
    from #P1
    union all
    select 
    Referencia,
    Designacao,
    Cor,
    Tamanho,
    EntregueSede,
    Stock
    from #P2
    union all
    select 
    Referencia,
    Designacao,
    Cor,
    Tamanho,
    EntregueSede,
    Stock
    from #P3
) a
group by Referencia,
Designacao,
cor,
Tamanho,
entreguesede,
stock
order by  1,2,3,4,6,7
```

Comment: ft.fdata is a date type field

Comment: ft.fdata is a date type field. as for and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '% + + '%' what it shoulds be and isnull(sz.nome,'') like '% + @insert_variable_here + '%'
what it does is select any warehouse by its name. I adapted this query from another one i use for a different purpose. It's problably not very useful here, since i use other criteria that gets the content i want, so discard it.
as for order by ColumnNumber does it have any performance issues?
as for your point 4, regarding sub-selects, can you give me an example based on my query to obtain the same result, but using a sub-query?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Regarding isnull(sz.nome,'') like '% + + '%' I was only wondering about it because without a variable isnull(sz.nome,'') = '' would have achieved a far better performance than isnull(sz.nome,'') like '% + + '%'. Regarding point 3 (ORDER BY), as much as I know and already stated above it is not relevant for performance so you can ignore it if you only care about the performance. However, it would be performance relevant if you actually do not need the order. Means if you could remove certain columns form the ORDER BY, it would affect performance positively.

Comment: I added two examples. Regarding point 4, you need to try and adapt my example to fit your code. But the main idea is to calculate the sums with a sub-query. In your case, if you have 1'000 rows, your sum's are calculated 1'000 time (for each row once, which can take ages in some situations). With my example, you calculate them once in a bigger query (this might not work well if your sl-table is super huge, but otherwise should work always).